# Java annotations - code simplifications

Tags: java, spring, testing, annotations, spring-test

I am looking for a way to simplify the following code.

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        // My configuration classes
})
public class MyServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        Assert.assertTrue(service != null);
    }
}
```

I have many configuration classes and I don't want to put them into each test class. So I got the idea to create my own annotation:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        // My configuration classes
})
public @interface IntegrationTests {
}
```

I try to use it in the following way:

```
@IntegrationTests
public class MyServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        Assert.assertTrue(service != null);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: `@Autowired` indicates spring, is that correct?

Comment: @Thomas: yes I use Spring.

Comment: Did you try adding `@Target` and `@Retention` as indicated by the [docs on spring's custom annotations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotation-stereotype)?

Comment: @Thomas: No, I didn't but I tried to use axtavt's solution and it works fine. So, the problem is solved. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can place these annotation on a superclass:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        // My configuration classes
})
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest { ... }
```

.

```
public class MyServiceTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest { ... }
```

This approach also allows you to declare common `@Autowired` dependencies in the base class and customize `@ContextConfiguration` classes in concrete tests.

Answer (score 7):

The reason your custom *composed annotation* did not work is that JUnit does not support `@RunWith` as a meta-annotation. Thus, when you compose your annotation as follows...

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { /* configuration classes */ })
public @interface IntegrationTests {
}
```

... it is **JUnit** that cannot see that you want to use the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`.

Spring Framework 4.0 and greater should have no problem seeing the declarations of `@WebAppConfiguration` and `@ContextConfiguration` used as meta-annotations.

In other words, the following should work for you:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { /* configuration classes */ })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface IntegrationTests {
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@IntegrationTests
public class MyServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        assertNotNull(service);
    }
}
```

As an alternative, you can use an `abstract` base test class as recommended by axtavt.

Regards,

Sam (author of the Spring TestContext Framework)